# Interpolating variables in HEREDOCs

Tags: php

I'd like to interpolate some variables into a HEREDOC string, but it is giving me errors, the code is this:

```
$htmlViewAppointments .= <<<EOT

        <tr><td>$obj['Year']</td></tr>

EOT;
```

Comment: shall we guess the errors or would you like to post them?

Comment: I'm going to use that one from now on ---^

Comment: The error was, exactly, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\Calendar-WithFrames\Utilities\ViewAppointments.php on line 20`

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$htmlViewAppointments .= <<<EOT

        <tr><td>{$obj['Year']}</td></tr>

EOT;
```

Comment: @deceze: why using constants and later PHP will substitute it with the key!

Comment: Except it won't! → http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: `$obj[Year]` worked fine for me. Also, the answer here works as well, although `$obj[Year]` seems easier to me.

Comment: @Akam: My answer wasn't an exact duplicate, but I deleted it since both of them are similar. No need to be rude :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: You are welcome to edit mine and add additional info